# Showing a way that answers don't answer your question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

What I want to propose is to add a bit more information to the initial view of the question, that is when it's in list form. What I recommend, is that it is shown what the highest ranking answer is.

If I were to see a question with very few votes on an answer than I would be more like to go into that question and either, vote up questions that I feel do answer the question, or, write my own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree for one simple reason: The highest ranking answer is not always helpful, the right one or a good written answer. I don't see how this would do any good. You should also look at questions based on their topic (you might learn something new, or you can add something of value despite a high-upvoted answer), not on their already added answers.